# how to copy files from android to windows share using python?

Tags: android, python, smb

Im trying to copy some files to and from a windows share. I am using python 2.7 and the [pysmb library](https://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/api/smb_SMBConnection.html). This works fine with win7, but not with android. I build my connection over VPN with `SMBConnection`. `listShares` and `listPath` is working. Under win7 there is no problem using also `os.path.isdir` or `shutil.copyfile`. But that does not work with android. This is my code:

```
server_name = '192.168.168.12'  
conn = SMBConnection(username=username, password=password, my_name='waldi2'
                 remote_name=server_name, domain=domain, use_ntlm_v2=True,
                 sign_options=SMBConnection.SIGN_WHEN_SUPPORTED, is_direct_tcp=True)
connected = conn.connect(server_name, 445)
# obtain a list of shares:
Response = conn.listShares(timeout=30)  # !!!working, shows e.g.('  Share[', 20, '] =', u'JBW_in')
os.path.isdir('//192.168.168.12/JBW_in/')    # is False with android, True with win7 !??

shutil.copyfile('/sdcard/waldi2_0/data/stop.txt', '//192.168.168.12/JBW_in/stop.txt')
```

This is no prob with win7, but with android it throws:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//192.168.168.12/JBW_in/stop.txt'
```

Any clues? would be very very welcome ....

Or maybe alternative approaches to manage some python-based file-exchange between android and windows-server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understund you correctly you are trying to connect to an android device via SMB. By my knowledge android doesnt have support for SMB server natively, but you could install a third-party app with a SMB server.

Comment: No - I want to access a windows share from android - somehow. I thought it would be the smartest way using SMB-protocol. But now I have doubts ...

Comment: It seems I was fooled by my experiments using my client-code - which is supposed to run on android - on a windows-system (as client) to test connectivity to the windows-server-share. There is no pysmb needed at all to access the share. That is probably why all os- and shutil-functions work on win and not on android. I was misled, that this is due to pysmb. pysmb has it's own methods: deleteFiles/storeFile/retrieveFile. But didn't get them working until now ...